# Convert C# class to .dll file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vscode-extensions

So, I was working on my class, and I want it to be a .dll file.

I searched online, and it says: "Here's the step...", meanwhile they just say "Visual Studio Code is Visual Studio.". I want a .dll class file entirely on VS Code, I can install extensions to make it work, but I can't find it. All answers accepted.

(Sorry for bad English. Thank you.)

Comment: first you need any .net-sdk installed (e.g. .net 7, .net framework, .net core 3 or whatever). That sdk brings a build-tool - for instance `dotnet`. Then within VS Code you can use that build-tool to compile your source-code-files to an assembly.

Comment: What kind of project is it? If it's a library, it is as simple as _building_ it.

Comment: _"they just say "Visual Studio Code is Visual Studio.""_ - whoever says that is wrong. VS is a full blown IDE, while VS Code is a gloryfied and highly extensible text editor.

Comment: You don't just "convert a cs-file to a dll". You can compile a **project** (that essentially *consists* of many source-code-files as well as references to other projects) to an assembly, though.

Comment: ^^ That said: a single .cs file containing a class does not make up a buildable project, yet. So, if that's all you have, please tell us. In that case, we need to take a few steps back.

Comment: Microsoft even has a Tutorial on that: [Tutorial: Create a .NET class library using Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-7-0) It literally walks you through the process in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: One additional possible point of confusion here: the code in a dll file MUST be compiled and linked. You don't get to put raw source code in a dll file that you can just open and change with a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project and make it a class library. Put your class in that project. It will compile to a DLL.